# Converting Relation data into Json Keys and Values

Tags: json, sql-server, relational-database

I am having requirement to convert relational data into JSON data. I am having data in relational data, consuming that data I have to create JSON key and JSON values. So JSON key will be in one column and JSON value for that key will be in another column. I tried simple SQL query using for JSON PATH, but it doesn't work for me.

Below is the pay load how I need to generate.

```
"domesticCallRates": {
    "F2M": {
      "EV2D": "0.00",
      "EV2O": "0.11"
    },
    "local": {
      "C213": "0.01",
      "EV2D": "0.02",
      "EV2O": "0.03"
    },
    "national": {
      "EV2D": "0.04",
      "EV2O": "0.05"
    }
  },

      "internationalCallRates": {`"0": {
      "$Landline": "6",
      "$Mobile": "6",
      "country": "India"
    },
    "1": {
      "$Landline": "3",
      "$Mobile": "3",
      "country": "Indonesia"
    }
  },
```

And below is the data in my tables:

[image]

Below is my attempt.

```
  SELECT 
Quote_id, 
   (
SELECT [EV2D], [value]
FROM (VALUES
      ('EV2D', CONVERT(varchar(max), Requested_RatePerMin_ExGST))
   ) v ([EV2D], [value])
   FOR JSON PATH
   ) AS F2M
FROM [Pricing].[Voice_Domestic_CallRates_NonStandard] FOR JSON AUTO
```

And output what I got is

```
[
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.1100"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13952,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0500"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.1100"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13953,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0500"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.1100"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0000"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Quote_id":13955,
      "F2M":[
         {
            "EV2D":"EV2D",
            "value":"0.0500"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Similar to above internationalcall data in relational data.

[image]

Comment: Please, post your current attempt and describe the problems you have. Where does the data for the `"internationalCallRates"` part of the output JSON come from? Thanks.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I am still seeking help to achieve this requirement. Any alternate inputs will be helpful